# In CSS what is the difference between "width: fit-content;" and "width: "fit-content(some_value);"?

Tags: css

MDN web docs describes fit-content as a function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#fit-content

```
width: fit-content(20em);
```

I can't find any reference to fit-content being defined as a value without the parentheses as it is  here:

```
figure {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#preferred-size-properties) to find them:

> Value: auto |  | min-content | max-content | fit-content(`<length-percentage>`)

This is the Box Sizing Level 3 specification.

Later in [the Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#sizing-values) you can read:

> New values:    stretch | fit-content | contain

And

> fit-content
>
> Essentially fit-content(stretch) i.e. min(max-content, max(min-content, stretch)).

So `fit-content` = `fit-content(stretch)`

> stretch
>
> Applies stretch-fit sizing, attempting to match the size of the box’s margin box to the size of its containing block. See § 7.1 Stretch-fit Sizing: filling the containing block.